# Explain how the Phenomenal Conservatism and Common Sense Privilege arguments works to justify belief in other minds

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind, argumentation, explanation

Please explain how the Phenomenal Conservatism and Common Sense Privilege argument works to justify belief in other minds.

Here it is written that it is used to justify belief in other minds, but I did not understand how it works.

https://iep.utm.edu/phen-con/

Please explain in more detail.

thank you